# Cancel a transfer in UCMA

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

Does anyone know how to cancel a running transfer, using UCMA 4??

In my app, I'm having a call from UserA to my UCMA app, that I start to transfer to another caller (UserB), by initiating a self-trasnfer with a B2BUA.

I'm running a timewheel (UCMA timer functionality), that should cancel the transfer when expires, but leave the established call (between USerA and the app) and let that stay established.

The transfer that I want to cancel is initiated by

```
AudioVideoCall call = new AudioVideoCall(_conversation);
call.BeginTransfer(call, TransferCompletedCB, call);
```

EDIT 22-09-14 13:29:
If I terminate Call2 of my B2BUA, then the idle call will be terminated correctly. But, my established call will enter 'Terminating...' state too. How can I prevent that my original call, that has been placed in B2BUA as call leg 1, is terminating??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can actually cancel the call by using .BeginTerminate of your 2nd call leg of the B2BUA. I even implemented a timer that can cancel the transfer if call not answered within the timer.